# Xamarin iOS Application suspended in Monitor when UICollectionViewFlowLayout.PrepareLayout()

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

Xamarin iOS application infinitely suspended when `CollectionView.IsVisible = false` on start up.

on Android, It works. However, on iOS, setting `CollectionView.IsVisible = false` resulted in application freezed.

```
    <StackLayout
        Margin="0,20,0,0">

        <Button
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="100"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"
            Text="Click Me"/>

        <CollectionView
            x:Name="Collection"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            IsVisible="False">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="4"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout
                        Margin="10,10,10,10">
                        <Image
                            WidthRequest="50"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            Source="{local:ImageResource CollectionView.Image.png}"/>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is [reproducible project](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/64640084).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **workaround** to solve this for iOS, you could set `Visiable` of **CollectionView** after Layout is initialized.

For example, remove `IsVisible="False"` from **Xaml**, then set it in **ContentPage.cs** in `OnAppearing` method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Collection.IsVisible = false;
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug in Xamarin? If this is a bug, I will make an issue on Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: @ibocon I'm not sure, but it should be a feature request at least. You could submit it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) in Github. Then we can follow it  up there later. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.